# Use python requests to download csv file

Tags: csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I am wanting to create a program that can run either weekly or daily to scrape data from a website and download the data in csv format. I was wondering if this was possible to use with Python because that is my preferred application to use, if at all possible how do you suggest I go about it. The website I am wanting to use is: https://finance.yahoo.com/ with the (S&P 500) data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what table you're looking to convert into a csv. Yahoo doesn't block requests.

If you know your way around pandas:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC')[0]
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: By doing this will it update as the data from yahoo updates??

Comment: First, I would build out your needs.. and do it manually a couple times to understand exactly what you need. You'll need to schedule whatever code you come up with for hourly/daily.